# How to manage a crawler URL frontier?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, forkjoinpool

Guys

I have the following code to add visited links on my crawler.
After extracting links i have a **for loop** which loop thorough each individual **href tags**.

And after i have visited a link , opened it , i will add the URL to  a visited link collection variable defined above.

```
private final Collection<String> urlForntier = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
```

The crawler implementation is mulithread and assume if i have visited 100,000 urls, if i didn't terminate the crawler it will grow day by day . and It will create memory issues ? Please , what option do i have to refresh the variable without creating inconsistency across threads ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your crawlers are any good, managing the crawl frontier quickly becomes difficult, slow and error-prone.

Luckily, your don't need to write this yourself, just write your crawlers to use consume the [URL Frontier](https://github.com/crawler-commons/url-frontier) API and plug-in an implementation that suits you.

See https://github.com/crawler-commons/url-frontier

Answer (score 1):

The most usable way for modern crawling systems is to use [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases.

This solution is notable slower than `HashSet`. That is why you can leverage different caching strategy like a [Redis](http://redis.io/), or even [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)s

But including specific nature of URL, I'd like to recommend [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure that gives you lot of options to manipulate and search by url string. (Discussion of java implementation can be found on this Stackoevrflow [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218905/need-memory-efficient-way-to-store-tons-of-strings-was-hat-trie-implementation))

Comment: Thanks Dewfy ! I wonder when is the variable will be cleared , if i run like 10000 years how much memeory then i need ? how do solve this ? even thoug i use Trie stacture u suggested

Comment: @danielad from open statistic by Google average length of url is 90 symbols, for today Google reports about 50 billions (5*10^10) web pages, Some Trie implementations state that we can keep this structure with memory efficiency as O(N). Making simple multiplication `90*5*10^10 = 4.5*10^12`(bytes) = 4191(Gb) Not so large number for modern computer

Answer (score -1):

1. As per question, I would recommend using [Redis](http://redis.io/) to replace use of Collection. It's in-memory database for data structure store and super fast to insert and retrieve data with support of all standard data structures.In your case [Set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#sets) and you can check existence of key in set with [SISMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/SISMEMBER) command).
2. [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is also good to explore.